# Non-greedy matching in Treetop/PEG?

Tags: regex, peg, treetop

How would I do something like this in Treetop?

```
/.+?;/
```

It seems like the only way is to do:

```
[^;]+ ';'
```

Which is kind of ugly.. any other way? `.+?` doesn't seem to work..

Comment: in 'parslet' I would do `rule(:line) { (str(";").absent? >> any).repeat(1) >> str(";") }` which I guess is the same as your second  option.

Answer (score 11):

PEGs are greedy and blind by default, that means they eat as much input as they can and they do not consider what comes afterwards:

`S <- P1* P2` (greedy, blind)

That can be considerably easy fixed though by making use of the ordered choice (and without using lookaheads):

`S <- P1 S / P2` (greedy, non-blind)

`S <- P2 / P1 S` (lazy, non-blind)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I learnt PEGs are greedy, and there's no way around it. Lookaheads can be used to mimic this behavior though, like `!(';' .)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Treetop, but would `/[^;]+;/` work?

From a quick search, I saw suggestion that Treetop doesn't do greedy nor lazy (non-greedy) quantifiers, and that the `+` is actually a possessive quantifier (represented by `++` in other regex flavours).

If this is the case, I'm not sure you've got any other regex-based options than the negated class.

Comment: `/[^;]+;/` works, it's written as `[^;]+ ';'`, like shown in my question. But I was hoping there was a better way.