# Why does *any* not backtrack in this example?

Tags: dart, petitparser

I'm trying to understand why in the following example I do not get a match on f2. Contrast that with f1 which does succeed as expected.

import 'package:petitparser/petitparser.dart';
    import 'package:petitparser/debug.dart';

```dart
main() {
  showIt(p, s, [tag = '']) {
    var result = p.parse(s);
    print('''($tag): $result ${result.message}, ${result.position} in:
$s
123456789123456789
''');
  }
  final id = letter() & word().star();
  final f1 = id & char('(') & letter().star() & char(')');
  final f2 = id & char('(') & any().star() & char(')');
  showIt(f1, 'foo(a)', 'as expected');
  showIt(f2, 'foo(a)', 'why any not matching a?');
  final re1 = new RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]\w*\(\w*\)');
  final re2 = new RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]\w*\(.*\)');
  print('foo(a)'.contains(re1));
  print('foo(a)'.contains(re2));
}
```

The output:

```dart
(as expected): Success[1:7]: [f, [o, o], (, [a], )] null, 6 in:
foo(a)
123456789123456789

(why any not matching a?): Failure[1:7]: ")" expected ")" expected, 6 in:
foo(a)
123456789123456789

true
true
```

I'm pretty sure the reason has to do with the fact that *any* matches the closing paren. But when it then looks for the closing paren and can't find it, shouldn't it:

- backtrack the last character
- assume the *any().star()* succeeded with just the 'a'
- accept the final paren and succeed

Also in contrast I show the analagous regexps that do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you analyzed correctly, the *any* parser in your example consumes the closing parenthesis. And the *star* parser wrapping the *any* parser is eagerly consuming as much input as possible.

Backtracking as you describe is not automatically done by PEGs (parsing expression grammars). Only the *ordered choice* backtracks automatically.

To fix your example there are multiple possibilities. Most strait forward one is to not make *any* match the closing parenthesis:

```dart
id & char('(') & char(')').neg().star() & char(')')
```

or

```dart
id & char('(') & pattern('^)').star() & char(')')
```

Alternatively you can use the *starLazy* operator. Its implementation is using the *star* and *ordered choice* operators. An explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2225208/82303).

```dart
id & char('(') & any().starLazy(char(')')) & char(')')
```

Comment: The language comment shouldn't be necessary anymore since a few months when the Dart tag was added.